# How to check class parent from BuildContext?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I'm implementing a commerce app and the focus now is on the three components: `CartPage`, `CatalogPage` and `ProductListItem`. The `ProductListItem` component is reused on two pages, cart and catalog. So inside `ProductListItem` Widget I must know what class is your parent to return the specific component. So far I mean to use `BuildContext` object to get some information from parent. If no this way, I mean on use a static string to check the parent, passing it on constructor when create `ProductListItem` component.

```
class ProductListItem extends StatefulWidget {

  final Product product;

  ProductListItem(this.product);

  @override
  _ProductListItemState createState() => _ProductListItemState(product);
}

class _ProductListItemState extends State<ProductListItem> {
  final Product product;
  int amount = 1;

  _ProductListItemState(this.product);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // if (parent is Cart) return 1;
  // else if (parent is Catalog) return 2;
  }
}
```

I'm accepting suggestions for other changes too.

Answer (score 0):

BuildContext objects are passed to WidgetBuilder functions (such as StatelessWidget.build), and are available from the State.context member. Some static functions (e.g. showDialog, Theme.of, and so forth) also take build contexts so that they can act on behalf of the calling widget, or obtain data specifically for the given context.

Each widget has its own BuildContext, which becomes the parent of the widget returned by the StatelessWidget.build or State.build function. (And similarly, the parent of any children for RenderObjectWidgets.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want get history of Navigator to check parent.
Currently Navigator not support to get history of Navigator. But Flutter team is will update this feature on Navigator 2.0, They are done and merge to master. Waiting for next release.

[How to get _history from NavigatorState](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35715)

[Navigator 2.0](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45938)

On your case, temporary, pass flag to Detail Page for Parent.